# How to uncompress Gzipped with Apache Spark Java

Tags: json, apache-spark, rdd

i have a sequence file. In this file is each value compressed json file with GZipped. My Problem, how to read in the gzipped json files with Apache Spark ?

for this my code,

```
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext("local", "sequencefile");
    JavaPairRDD<String, byte[]> file = jsc.sequenceFile("file:\\E:\\part-00004", String.class, byte[].class);

    JavaRDD<String> map = file.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, byte[]>, String>() {
        public String call(Tuple2<String, byte[]> stringTuple2) throws Exception {
            byte[] uncompress = uncompress(stringTuple2._2);
            return uncompress.toString();
        }
    });
```

But this code func not working. 
Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

While creating spark context use the constructor which will also take the spark configuration as third parameter.

Set the spark configuration value for key “org.apache.hadoop.io.compression.codecs”

As below

“org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec”